# Bootstrap Columns not aligning properly.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I have this code to create a 4 column layout in Bootstrap 3. They display perfectly in desktops and mobile devices. However, in tablets, the third column goes to the left and the fourth column goes into a third row. There is a white space in the second column on the left where the third column should actually be in order to create the 2 col-sm-6 layout.

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 noticia">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" >
                        <p class="fecha">17 de Abril de 2016</p>
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Some text</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Leer Más...</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 noticia">
                        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" >
                        <p class="fecha">17 de Abril de 2016</p>
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Some text.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Leer Más...</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 noticia">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" >
                        <p class="fecha">17 de Abril de 2016</p>
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Some text.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Leer Más...</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 noticia">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" >
                        <p class="fecha">17 de Abril de 2016</p>
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Some text.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Leer Más...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

The only style I have for this div are the following:

```
.noticia{
padding:10px;
max-width:100%;
```

}

```
.noticia img{
    max-width:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
    .noticia h2{
        font-size:20px;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;  
        font-weight:medium;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }
```

This is a screenshot of what I am saying. Any help would be amazing. I have spent almost an hour looking into this and it is probably something I am doing wrong, but I am just starting with Bootstrap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put this code after your second `.noticia` div

```
<div class="clearfix hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
```

Comment: It'd be nice if there was an explanation attached to this. AFAIK the bootstrap grid system should work correctly even without the `clearfix`, but for some reason it doesn't. (BTW. Another way to fix this is to set a fixed height on all columns)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with bootstrap, please make sure to include this code in your css (or that's already included) this code aims to enable bootstrap to better calculate the colums and their paddings

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```